# How to force table header (and its column) to be smaller than its limit with CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I made a table and with 6 columns the first of which I have given "id = 'Day'" in the style sheet I made the width of it 50px but this is taking up too much space on the screen. When I try to change it to something smaller it will not get smaller than 50px. Is there a way to force it to be smaller than 50px? Code bellow.

```css
th#Day {
    width: 20px;
}
table {
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th id="Day">Day</th>
        <th>Event</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Phone Number</th>
        <th>URL</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The width of the table does not effect the width of the Day column but I am not able to make the Day column smaller than 50 px as mentioned above.

I have tried setting the min-width to be smaller but that does not change it and have not found any solutions on popular sites.

Answer (score 0):

From the tests I have done, it seems that the problem is in the table's size. By commenting it is possible to modify the width of the columns (which cannot be less than its content, from what I am noticing, it's a new thing for me too) but otherwise, as you can see, it works

https://codepen.io/loremaru/pen/vYawPpq

```
#Day {
    width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#Event{
      width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
table {
/*     width: 200px; */
}
```

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th id="Day">Day</th>
        <th id="Event">Event</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Phone Number</th>
        <th>URL</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I actually just noticed I never set the width of the table I wrote that wrong in my question. Other than that are you able to think of anything that might have caused this issue?

Comment: no idea. Maybe some other width?